# Enviar por método POST un arreglo de select en Django

Tags: django

```
<form id="fcontact"  method="POST" action="contacto.html">

              {% csrf_token %}
              <select name="items[]">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
              </select>
              ...
              N_SELECTS
              ...
              <select name="items[]">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
              </select>
               <button id='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send comment!</button>
    </form>
```

En la vista

```
if request.method=='POST':
        list1 = request.POST.getlist('items')
        context={'a1':list1}
        return render(request,'print.html',context)
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Hola mucho gusto.

Comment: Requiero pasar un array de las respuestas escogidas con los select.

Comment: Pero no se como enviarlos por metodos post, ni como recogerlos del lado de la vista en el framwork Django

Comment: ¿Todos los selects son iguales y tienen la misma información?, ¿no estás usando formularios de Django?

Comment: Si todos los select son iguales.

Comment: Pero la respuesta de cada select puede ser diferente y en el codigo completo va enlazado con otro valor identificador.

Comment: Ejemplo    {Luis:Mercedes ,Julio:Saab ,Pepe:Volvo ,Pedro ,Saab} . Los select en el codigo completo van hacer variables dependiendo del numero de personas

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes a qué usuario le pertenece cada respuesta? No veo en tu código algo que indique eso. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es actualizar tu pregunta con toda la información para poder ayudarte: modelos, vistas, formularios, etc.

Answer (score -1):

TEMPLATE

```
<form id="fcontact"  method="POST" action="contacto.html">

              {% csrf_token %}
              <select name="items[]">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
              </select>
              ...
              N_SELECTS
              ...
              <select name="items[]">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
              </select>
               <button id='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send comment!</button>
    </form>
```

En la vista

```
if request.method=='POST':
        lista = request.POST.getlist('items[]')
        # lista, forma un arreglo.
```